# Issue with initializing Firebase Auth for React Native using AsyncStorage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, firebase-authentication

I'm having an issue with implementing SMS authentication through Firebase. I've been trying to study the documentation and use Google to find a solution, but so far without success. I have a simple page with one input field and a "Send" button. I'm developing an Android app using Expo.

However, when trying to initialize Firebase Auth for React Native, Expo gives me the following error:

WARN [2023-09-05T05:59:10.503Z] @firebase/auth: Auth (10.3.1):
You are initializing Firebase Auth for React Native without providing AsyncStorage. Auth state will default to memory persistence and will not persist between sessions. In order to persist auth state, install the package "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage" and provide it to initializeAuth:

```
import { initializeAuth, getReactNativePersistence } from 'firebase/auth';
import ReactNativeAsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
const auth = initializeAuth(app, {
  persistence: getReactNativePersistence(ReactNativeAsyncStorage)
});
```

Could you please explain how I can solve this issue? I've already installed the package "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage", but I don't understand how to properly use it to initialize Firebase Auth.

```
  import React, { useState } from "react";
    import { Alert, Button, StyleSheet, TextInput, View } from "react-native";
    import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
    import { getAuth, signInWithPhoneNumber } from "firebase/auth";
    import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";
    import { initializeAuth, getReactNativePersistence } from 'firebase/auth';
    import ReactNativeAsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

    const firebaseConfig = {
      apiKey: "AIzaSyD5Qg_t9KR4TmLr2p14E2aODO9UV5RehUE",
      authDomain: "sharq-9ec25.firebaseapp.com",
      databaseURL: "https://sharq-9ec25-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com",
      projectId: "sharq-9ec25",
      storageBucket: "sharq-9ec25.appspot.com",
      messagingSenderId: "613514564466",
      appId: "1:613514564466:web:c76f60d1a5d151689e83eb",
      measurementId: "G-BGWW40HYBJ"
    };


initializeApp(firebaseConfig); // initialize Firebase

const asyncStorage = AsyncStorage;

const FirebasePhoneAuth = () => {
  const [phoneNumber, setPhoneNumber] = useState(""); //  для номера телефона
  const [verificationCode, setVerificationCode] = useState(""); //  для кода подтверждения
  const [confirmationResult, setConfirmationResult] = useState(null); //  для результатов 

  const sendVerificationCode = async () => {
    const auth = getAuth();
    const appVerifier = null; //  reCAPTCHA

    try {
      // Отправка кода подтверждения на указанный номер телефона
      const confirmation = await signInWithPhoneNumber(auth, phoneNumber, appVerifier);
      setConfirmationResult(confirmation); // Сохранение результатов подтверждения для последующего использования
    } catch (error) {
      Alert.alert("Ошибка", "Не удалось отправить код подтверждения");
    }
  };
  // Подтверждение кода подтверждения
  const confirmVerificationCode = async () => {
    try {
      await confirmationResult.confirm(verificationCode);
      Alert.alert("Успех", "Номер телефона успешно подтвержден");

      // Сохранение номера телефона в AsyncStorage
      await asyncStorage.setItem("phoneNumber", phoneNumber);
    } catch (error) {
      Alert.alert("Ошибка", "Не удалось подтвердить номер телефона");
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        placeholder="Введите номер телефона"
        onChangeText={(value) => setPhoneNumber(value)}
      />
      <Button onPress={sendVerificationCode} title="Отправить код подтверждения" />

      {confirmationResult && (
        <>
          <TextInput
            style={styles.input}
            placeholder="Введите код подтверждения"
            onChangeText={(value) => setVerificationCode(value)}
          />
          <Button onPress={confirmVerificationCode} title="Подтвердить код подтверждения" />
        </>
      )}
    </View>
  );
};
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
      },
      input: {
        width: "80%",
        height: 40,
        borderWidth: 1,
        marginBottom: 20,
        paddingHorizontal: 10,
      },
    });
export default FirebasePhoneAuth;
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you call `getAuth()` for an instance of `App` that hasn't initialized its `Auth` object, it will [call `initializeAuth()` for you](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/fbd8e0e2e17befcd514775e018fcc4f4c5ecfc43/packages/auth/index.rn.ts#L70-L72). In your code, you do this inside `sendVerificationCode()` which leads to the warning you see.

To make sure that `initializeAuth()` is called before you consume it using `getAuth()` in any of your components, you should place it immediately below the call to `initializeApp()`. It's best practice to do this in a common place such as a file called `firebase.js` or similar:

```
// ./services/firebase.js
import { initializeApp, getApp } from "firebase/app";
import { initializeAuth, getAuth, getReactNativePersistence } from 'firebase/auth';
import ReactNativeAsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

const firebaseConfig = {
  /* ... */
};

// initialize Firebase App
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
// initialize Firebase Auth for that app immediately
const auth = initializeAuth(app, {
  persistence: getReactNativePersistence(ReactNativeAsyncStorage)
});

export { app, auth, getApp, getAuth };
```

Then in your component, you'd bring it in and use as normal:

```
// ./components/someComponent.jsx
import { getApp, getAuth } from "../services/firebase";

/* component code */
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I did as you wrote and the error disappeared, but there is no result. Could you please check my code? Here is the link: https://snack.expo.dev/VRK1spXoK.

For now, everything is on one page for testing purposes, but later I will create a separate file ./services/firebase.js.

Comment: Define "there is no result" - do you get the error alert? do you see any requests made on the network?

Comment: When the submit button is pressed, a warning message pops up with the alert "Error: Failed to send confirmation code". However, there are no signs of life in the console or in the developer tools of EXPO. I suspect that I wrote some bad code somewhere, causing the button not to send the data to the network.

Comment: following what you did i get this error  ERROR  ReferenceError: Property 'auth' doesn't exist, js engine: hermes

Comment: @nab Corrected the typo.

Answer (score 1):

Before I created a file at the root of my folder that I named fireConfig.js the file contains the following code

```
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp, } from "firebase/app";
import { initializeAuth, getReactNativePersistence  } from "firebase/auth";
import ReactNativeAsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: 
  authDomain: 
  projectId:
  storageBucket: 
  messagingSenderId: 
  appId: 
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

initializeAuth(app, {
  persistence: getReactNativePersistence(ReactNativeAsyncStorage)
});


export default app;
```

Then in another file named form.js
always at the root of my folder create the following code

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TextInput,
  Button,
} from "react-native";

import { app } from "./fireConfig"
import {getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth";




const auth = getAuth(app);


const Form = () => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    // Initialiser le formulaire
    setEmail("");
    setPassword("");
  }, []);

  const handleLogin =async () => {
        
    await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
    .then((userCredential) => {
        // Signed in 
        const user = userCredential.user;
      
        // ...
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        const errorCode = error.code;
        const errorMessage = error.message;
        // ..
    });

  };

  const handleRegister = () => {
    // Effectuer une requête d'enregistrement
    // ...
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.title}>Formulaire de connexion</Text>
      <TextInput
        placeholder="E-mail"
        style={styles.input}
        value={email}
        onChangeText={(text) => setEmail(text)}
      />
      <TextInput
        placeholder="Mot de passe"
        style={styles.input}
        value={password}
        onChangeText={(text) => setPassword(text)}
        secureTextEntry={true}
      />
      <Button
        title="Connexion"
        style={styles.button}
        onPress={handleLogin}
      />
      <Button
        title="Enregistrer"
        style={styles.button}
        onPress={handleRegister}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 24,
    fontWeight: "bold",
  },
  input: {
    width: 200,
    height: 40,
    borderColor: "gray",
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderRadius: 5,
  },
  button: {
    width: 100,
    height: 40,
    backgroundColor: "blue",
    borderRadius: 5,
  },
});

export default Form;

List item
```