# @firebase/auth: Auth (10.4.0): Firebase Auth for React Native without providing AsyncStorage

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I am trying to connect my app with firebase. Which is working the data is getting saved but i am getting this warning:

> You are initializing Firebase Auth for React Native without providing AsyncStorage.

Because of that I have to login every time I reload the app.

```
import { getApp, initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";
import ReactNativeAsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";
import { getReactNativePersistence } from "firebase/auth";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "your-api-key",
  authDomain: "your-auth-domain",
  projectId: "your-project-id",
  storageBucket: "your-storage-bucket",
  messagingSenderId: "your-messaging-sender-id",
  appId: "your-app-id",
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig, {
  persistence: getReactNativePersistence(ReactNativeAsyncStorage),
  storageBucket: AsyncStorage,
});

const firebaseAuth = getAuth(app);
const firestoreDB = getFirestore(app);

export { app, firebaseAuth, firestoreDB };
```

Tried different ways of intializing the app but still the same warning

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Issue with initializing Firebase Auth for React Native using AsyncStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77048569/issue-with-initializing-firebase-auth-for-react-native-using-asyncstorage)